# PASCAL/FORTRAN/C++ compilers

Tags: c++, pascal

I am retired and having some time on my hands, got out my old DATA STRUCTURES textbooks from the 80s. I got to thinking how much I would like to revive my skills in PASCAL/C++ and use the techniques in the books. About 4 years ago, I bought a distribution of UBUNTU on DVD and successfully loaded it. I could never find any mention of how to do any development even though the literature seemed to imply that UBUNTU included these compilers. I gave up on this but recently decided to try again. What is the best way to do software developmemnt on UBUNTU?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Pascal on Ubuntu (or anywhere for that matter) but I use the Eclipse IDE for Java development so would probably go with Eclipse and the CDT (C/C++ Developers Toolkit) although Monodevelop is another option.

http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

It will be more easy for developer to use *Synaptic* package manager instead of *Software Center* which is prepared for general users. So you could search for *-dev libs, *-doc, IDE's...

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

It up to you, but I suggest start testing IDE's then move to learn the underlaying CLI compilers and the development helpers (like: auto-tools, packaging...).

- PASCAL (free pascal IDE's): lazarus, fp-ide

  For user graphic interface development, you gonna see some difference then (Windows) in Linux most are using GTK libraries.
- FORTRAN (no IDE): gfortran (Fortran95 compiler)

  Using Gedit menu: View → Highlight Mode → Select: Fortran95
- C++ (There plenty of IDE's, Compilers, Editors..)

  g++ is the gnu c++ compiler (gcc c compiler)

  Geany is very simple IDE or editor. If you want very simple one like old style, Write-Compile-Run. (Most editors in Linux support code highlighting, You can use most of them)

  Eclipse with CDT plug-in is an advanced IDE

  Other IDE's: qtcreator (Qt GUI), netbean, anjuta (GTK+ GUI), codeblocks (wxWidget GUI), codelite, monodevelop (.NET, GTK GUI)..

Note:

Package names end with *-dev* are development headers & libraries, with *-doc* are documentations, most are development doc's, shares system libraries (dynamic) start or end with *lib*

You can even install all, try them for sometime and see what the best for you.

**Update:**

Concerning Ubuntu development (Debian Based) mainly: c, c++ & [python](https://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/programming-languages/python/)

Other languages which have very good support: java, perl, ruby, vala, c#, lua, lisp, ...